# mpirun command error while running a c program under linux

Tags: mpi

I have written a c program under Linux using mpi. I used *mpicc mpi2.c -o mpi2* to compile the program and used *mpirun -n 4 mpi2* to run the program. There was no error while complying but got error while running the program. The error "No such file or directory" is given, as shown [in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChtoQ.png)

Can anyone help me how do i solve this problem.

Comment: please directly copy/paste the error message into the question instead of linking to a screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what if you simply ?

```
mpirun -n 4 ./mpi2
```

Comment: @Bhagawat It is recommended to accept an answer to close the thread. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers